# SvcConfigEditor not an option with web.config

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

When I right click on the web.config file it does not give me the option to edit it in SvcConfigEditor.  yet when I make a class library it does.  Why would this be?  What is the best way to use the editor when my main project has wcf services?

Comment: Which Visual Studio version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start service configuration editor from the Tools menu -> WCF Service Configuration Editor.

Comment: And after you do that, you'll get it as an option when you right-click web.config.

Comment: I was browsing to the wrong one.  I had to use the one under visual studio tools